# If my men are taken prisoner, can I get them back?

Tags: mount-and-blade

In *Mount & Blade*, I was recently attacked by a Lord whose army outnumbered mine 2:1. I tried my best to avoid the fight, as I knew I wouldn't stand a chance, but he was adamant about fighting with me.

Needless to say, I lost. Badly. I managed to get captured, along with my 54 men. However, I was fortunate enough to escape from my captors. Unfortunately, it was only me and 2 of my heroes, leaving me with only 3 troops.

**Is there any way for me to get them back?** Say, if I were to capture a Lord from the Kingdom in which my men are being held?

[image]

Comment: is this mount and blade, or is this mount and blade: warband?

Comment: The first one. I haven't started Warband yet.

Comment: imo warband is the original but vastly improved, there really is no reason to play just the base game.  F&S is completely different, however.

Comment: In Warband, is there another way to get troops back?

Comment: nope, lost troops are lost, unfortunately.  I just asked to make sure the tag was correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to get your men back is to beat the lord that fought you in the first place and recruit his prisoners into your army(hopefully your former army is still there).

Considering you only have 3 units left, this is probably out of the picture at this point.

Comment: This tactic works for both soldiers and equipment.   More than once, I've been defeated by Deserters, captured, and had a favorite weapon (or book) stolen.  They also capture 20-50 of my soldiers.  Deserters don't seem to ever imprison/sell their prisoners, nor do they sell their loot.  After escaping, I raised a small army, found the Deserters, killed them, and retrieved my soldiers and favorite weapon/book.